# Flatten a nested JSON hierarchy in Python

Tags: python, json, jupyter-notebook, nested-loops, hierarchy

I'll preface this with I am not a developer by any means, but I was thrown this assignment and I am just lost. This is my first time using python and first time coding in 7+ years, and it's not going well.

The JSON I have is an organizational tree, where each level potentially has children underneath it.

I need to write a script in Python in Jupyter Notebook to flatten it into this format, or something similar where each new child is a new row.

```
 level1 | level2 | level3
 org1
 org1      org2
 org1      org2    org3
```

Here is the JSON:

```
[{
    "Id": "f035de7f",
    "Name": "Org1",
    "ParentId": null,
    "Children": [{
        "Id": "8c18a70d",
        "Name": "Org2",
        "ParentId": "f035de7f",
        "Children": []
    }, {
        "Id": "b4514099",
        "Name": "Org3",
        "ParentId": "f035de7f",
        "Children": [{
            "Id": "8abe58d1",
            "Name": "Org4",
            "Children": []
        }]
    }, {
        "Id": "8e35bdc3",
        "Name": "Org5",
        "ParentId": "f035de7f",
        "Children": [{
            "Id": "331fffbf",
            "Name": "Org6",
            "ParentId": "8e35bdc3",
            "Children": [{
                "Id": "3bc3e085",
                "Name": "Org7",
                "ParentId": "331fffbf",
                "Children": []
            }]
        }]
    }]
}]
```

I've tried a variety of for loops and have scoured the internet for days, but I think I'm missing some very basic knowledge to make this work. I would highly appreciate any help someone can give.

Here are my starters:

```
for item in orgs_json:
    orgs_json_children = item["Children"]
    orgs_list.append(orgs_json_children)
```

or

```
wanted = ['Children', 'Name']

for item in orgs_json[0]:
    details = [X["Name"] for X in orgs_json]
    for key in wanted:
        print(key, ':', json.dumps(details[key], indent=4))
    # Put a blank line at the end of the details for each item
    print()
```

Comment: `org3` is not a child of `org2` but of `org1` - you sure you want it to be `org1 > org2 > org3`?

Comment: You have `org1 > org2`, `org1 > org3 > org4` and `org1 > org5 > org6 > org7`, but no `org1 > org2 > org3`. How deep do these structures go?

Comment: Note: JSON is a *serialisation format*, not a data structure. The Python `json` module deserializes the format to Python dictionaries, lists, strings, and other basic types. It doesn't then matter where that data structure came from, it's just Python dictionaries and lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can process the nested structure with a stack:

- Start with the outermost list, *reversed*, as the stack, together with an empty tuple for each, to track the *organisation path*.
- In `while stack:` loop, take the top element from the stack. Do what you need to do with that organisation, like recording the name. Produce a row from the organisation path with the current organisation name added.
- Add all the elements in the `Children` key to the stack, together with the organisation path of the parent organisation.
- Loop until the stack is done.

The reversals are needed because taking elements from a stack gives them in reverse order. You still want to use a stack for this job (as opposed to a queue) because we want to output the information depth-first.

This would look like this:

```
def flatten_orgs(orgs):
    stack = [(o, ()) for o in reversed(orgs)]  # organisation plus path
    while stack:
        org, path = stack.pop()  # top element
        path += (org['Name'],)   # update path, adding the current name
        yield path               # give this path to the caller
        # add all children to the stack, with the current path
        stack += ((o, path) for o in reversed(org['Children']))
```

You can then loop over the above function to get all the paths:

```
>>> for path in flatten_orgs(orgs_json):
...     print(*path, sep='\t')
...
Org1
Org1    Org2
Org1    Org3
Org1    Org3    Org4
Org1    Org5
Org1    Org5    Org6
Org1    Org5    Org6    Org7
```

Answer (score 0):

You can recursively iterate on your data. Prefix represents the list of names seen so far, and data represents the list of dictionnaries that you still must study.

```
data = [{
    "Id": "f035de7f",
    "Name": "Org1",
    "ParentId": None,
    "Children": [{
        "Id": "8c18a70d",
        "Name": "Org2",
        "ParentId": "f035de7f",
        "Children": []
    }, {
        "Id": "b4514099",
        "Name": "Org3",
        "ParentId": "f035de7f",
        "Children": [{
            "Id": "8abe58d1",
            "Name": "Org4",
            "Children": []
        }],
    }, {
        "Id": "8e35bdc3",
        "Name": "Org5",
        "ParentId": "f035de7f",
        "Children": [{
            "Id": "331fffbf",
            "Name": "Org6",
            "ParentId": "8e35bdc3",
            "Children": [{
                "Id": "3bc3e085",
                "Name": "Org7",
                "ParentId": "331fffbf",
                "Children": []
            }],
        }],
    }],
}]



def flatten(data, prefix):
    if not data:
        return [prefix]

    result = []
    for org in data:
        name = org["Name"]
        result.extend(flatten(org["Children"], prefix + [name]))
    return result

print(flatten(data, []))
# [['Org1', 'Org2'], ['Org1', 'Org3', 'Org4'], ['Org1', 'Org5', 'Org6', 'Org7']]
```

The same, using yield:

```
def flatten(data, prefix):
    if not data:
        yield prefix

    for org in data:
        name = org["Name"]
        yield from flatten(org["Children"], prefix + [name])

print(list(flatten(data, [])))
```

If you need all the partial lists, the solution is shorter:

```
def flatten(data, prefix):
    yield prefix

    for org in data:
        name = org["Name"]
        yield from flatten(org["Children"], prefix + [name])

print(list(flatten(data, [])))
# [[], ['Org1'], ['Org1', 'Org2'], ['Org1', 'Org3'], ['Org1', 'Org3', 'Org4'], ['Org1', 'Org5'], ['Org1', 'Org5', 'Org6'], ['Org1', 'Org5', 'Org6', 'Org7']]
```

Answer (score 0):

A json recursive tree can have several roots and the leafs should not have to mandatory specify void childrens. For example, here is a tree with two roots 'a' and 'b', and nodes which only have a 'level' data which is the node depth ('children' is optional):

```
json_struct = [
    {
    'level': 'a0',
    'children': [{'level': 'a0.1',  'children':
                    [{'level': 'a0.1.1', 'children': []}]},
                 {'level': 'a0.2',  'children': [
                     {'level': 'a0.2.1', 'children': [
                            {'level': 'a0.2.1.1'},
                            {'level': 'a0.2.1.2'},
                            {'level': 'a0.2.1.3'},
                            {'level': 'a0.2.1.4', 'children': [{'level': 'a0.2.1.4.1'}, {'level': 'a0.2.1.4.2'}]}
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                  },
                 {'level': 'a0.3', 'children': []},
                 {'level': 'a0.4', 'children': [{'level': 'a0.4.1'}, {'level': 'a0.4.2', 'children': []}]}
                ]
    },
    {
        'level': 'b0',
        'children': [{'level': 'b0.1', 'children': [{'level': 'b0.1.1'}]},
                     {'level': 'b0.2', 'children': [{'level': 'b0.2.1', 'children': [
                         {'level': 'b0.2.1.1'},
                         {'level': 'b0.2.1.2'},
                         {'level': 'b0.2.1.3', 'children': [{'level': 'b0.2.1.3.1'}, {'level': 'b0.2.1.3.2'}]},
                         {'level': 'b0.2.1.4'}
                            ]
                        }]},
                     {'level': 'b0.3'}
                     ]
    }
]
```

The code must return the leaves and complete branch path until each leave:

```
def flatten_json_tree(nodes, lower_nodes_key='children', path=[]):
    if not nodes:       # void node
        yield path    # so it is a leaf

    for node in nodes:  # go on into each branch of the tree
        level = node['level']   # get node datas
        try:
            lower_nodes = node[lower_nodes_key]     # search for lower nodes
        except KeyError:
            lower_nodes = []    # no lower nodes

        yield from flatten_json_tree(lower_nodes, lower_nodes_key, path + [level])     # continue to explore the branch until leaf

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for path in list(flatten_json_tree(json_struct)):
        leaf = path[-1:][0]
        complete_path = ''
        for node in path:
            complete_path += node + (' -> ' if node is not leaf else '')
        print("LEAF: {:20s} PATH: {}".format(leaf, complete_path))
```

It displays:

1. LEAF: a0.1.1               PATH: a0 -> a0.1 -> a0.1.1
2. LEAF: a0.2.1.1             PATH: a0 -> a0.2 -> a0.2.1 -> a0.2.1.1
3. LEAF: a0.2.1.2             PATH: a0 -> a0.2 -> a0.2.1 -> a0.2.1.2
4. LEAF: a0.2.1.3             PATH: a0 -> a0.2 -> a0.2.1 -> a0.2.1.3
5. LEAF: a0.2.1.4.1           PATH: a0 -> a0.2 -> a0.2.1 -> a0.2.1.4 -> a0.2.1.4.1
6. LEAF: a0.2.1.4.2           PATH: a0 -> a0.2 -> a0.2.1 -> a0.2.1.4 -> a0.2.1.4.2
7. LEAF: a0.3                 PATH: a0 -> a0.3
8. LEAF: a0.4.1               PATH: a0 -> a0.4 -> a0.4.1
9. LEAF: a0.4.2               PATH: a0 -> a0.4 -> a0.4.2
10. LEAF: b0.1.1               PATH: b0 -> b0.1 -> b0.1.1
11. LEAF: b0.2.1.1             PATH: b0 -> b0.2 -> b0.2.1 -> b0.2.1.1
12. LEAF: b0.2.1.2             PATH: b0 -> b0.2 -> b0.2.1 -> b0.2.1.2
13. LEAF: b0.2.1.3.1           PATH: b0 -> b0.2 -> b0.2.1 -> b0.2.1.3 -> b0.2.1.3.1
14. LEAF: b0.2.1.3.2           PATH: b0 -> b0.2 -> b0.2.1 -> b0.2.1.3 -> b0.2.1.3.2
15. LEAF: b0.2.1.4             PATH: b0 -> b0.2 -> b0.2.1 -> b0.2.1.4
16. LEAF: b0.3                 PATH: b0 -> b0.3